# How do I convert a string that is valid json returned from a psycopg2 query into json that can be inserted to a mongo instance via pymongo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo, psycopg2

How do I convert a string that is valid json returned from a psycopg2 query into json that can be inserted to a mongo instance via pymongo?  I've tried a number of things, all of them unsuccessful.  I keep getting a TypeError on the insert to mongo `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`.

I'm using Python 2.7 and psycopg2 2.4.5, and pymongo 2.1 by the way.  I can upgrade if necessary, I just went with what installed by default using Ubuntu and apt-get.

```
import psycopg2
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
import ast
import json

connection = Connection()
db = connection['af_reports_test']
psa = db['psa']


cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT activity_json FROM \"edus\".\"ACTIVITIES\" WHERE         status='PUBLISHED'")
results = cur.fetchall()


for rec in results:
    for value in rec:   
        psa.insert(value)
```

Here is a sample of what I'm getting back from the database:

```
{"activity":{"to":{"users":["someone","someoneElse"]}}}
```

Also, here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getPSA.py", line 33, in <module>
    psa.insert(activity)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 300, in insert
    docs = [self.__database._fix_incoming(doc, self) for doc in docs]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 252, in _fix_incoming
    son = manipulator.transform_incoming(son, collection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/son_manipulator.py", line 73, in transform_incoming
    son["_id"] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(value))`? That will return `value` if it happens to fit within the (large) subset of data whose JSON representation is valid Python, and raise an exception in any other case. What are you actually trying to do there?

Comment: You are already retrieving JSON, why dump to JSON **again**, then interpret that as Python literals? Your code is making very little sense.

Comment: I've edited the code above to reflect my first attempt, which does not include ast.literal_eval or json.dumps(value).  I'm also including a sample of the string that I'm getting back from the database.

Comment: Can you print the `repr` and/or the `type` of what you're getting back, instead of the thing itself? I can't tell whether that's a `dict`, or a `str`…

Comment: Anyway, my suspicion is that what you're getting back is a JSON string representation of a `dict`, and what `psa.insert` wants is a `dict`, so, as my answer says, you want to use `json.loads`. (The only way to know that it's a JSON string is to know how it was generated, which I can't tell by looking at it, but hopefully _you_ know that.)

Comment: it's a str.  Your suggestion below to use json.loads worked.  I'm marking your response as the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, since you didn't give us the traceback or enough information to reproduce your problem, but I suspect it's this:

```
activity = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(value))
```

You're taking `value`, which is presumably some kind of Python object, calling `json.dumps` to turn it into a JSON string representing that object, then calling `ast.literal_eval` to turn it back into the original object. That can't possibly be useful.

Meanwhile, the error seems to be saying that you have a string when it's expecting some other kind of object (most likely a list or other mutable sequence). If `value` is already a JSON string, you want to use `json.loads` to get a Python object out of it. If it's a Python literal string itself, you want to use `ast.literal_eval` on the string, not on a JSON string representing the original string. If it's some other thing… well, we'd need to know what other thing to know how to decode it. The only thing I can be sure of is that there's no conceivable thing it could be for which your code would be useful.

Comment: `value` is a column in a SQL result row. The SQL retrieves only one column, `activity_json`, so presumably `rec[0]` would do without the inner loop here. If it already is JSON, the conversion step is not needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's true, but the inner loop isn't really _hurting_ anything here except to make the code more complicated than it needs to be. When things are this confused already, I think it's best to first figure out what he's actually dealing with and what he's trying to do with it, fix that, and only then explain ways to make it simpler.